# Generating multiple endpoints by retrieving WebAPI routes from appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

I need to generate multiple endpoints based on routes saved in appsettings.json, I mean I have one contoller and one method post that will return a generic entity but I would like the swagger would generate the endpoints, for example if you write in the appsettings.json "Product" and "Client"(I could that more other routes), the Swager will generate two endpoints(api/Products, api/Client) and so on ,but, using the same post method in one class controller because, I will retrieve the name of the view internnaly according related to other values nested to these sections(Endpoints)

Class Controller

```
public class GenericCrudController : ControllerBase

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody] EntityRequestBase request)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest();
            
            return Ok(entityService.GetEntities(request));
        }
```

Appsettings.json

```
 "Endpoints": {
      "Product": {
        "Path": "/api/Product",
        "ViewProduct": "productView"
      },
      "Client": {
        "Path": "/api/Client",
        "ViewClient": "clienttView"
      }
    }
```

[SWagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQAb5.png)